# Heat resistant material for Nickel Chromium Wire?

Tags: materials

This should be a pretty straight forward question but I can't seem to find the type of material that is used..

So I am making my own heating coil out of Nickel Chromium wire. I plan on using two bolts in a frame that hold the entire thing together. Obviously the bolts themselves are conductive so my plan is to wrap the bolts in the "heat resistant cardboard" that I see inside of hair dryers and other heating devices that use the same wire. Does anyone know which type of material this is, as I am sure normal cardboard would simply ignite...

Comment: Are you thinking of Mica? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mica#Built-up_mica

Comment: @JonathanRSwift That might be correct.... IF you had a heating element in contact with Mica you would have no problems wouldn't you? Also I was thinking cork might work well too..

Comment: Cork - really ? Is that considered non-combustible?

Comment: What's the maximum temperature of your NiChrome? What other safety features does your system have (e.g. thermal fuse?) to prevent rising above this? Cork starts to degrade significantly above 200C https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00200161

Comment: Flame resistant and cardboard do not belong in the same sentence.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift My max temp would be 400F which is slightly above 200C so then you are correct that cork would not work. Either way I think the sheet Mica will work. I will simply wrap it around the bolts

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Flame resistant <> heat resistant

Comment: @JonathanRSwift If you wish to post your Mica solution as an answer I will accept since that does answer my question

Comment: But as your title says == Heat / Fire resistant cardboard.

Comment: FYI there are polymer films such as polymide/kapton you could use as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Heat resistant cardboard" that you are describing is likely '[Built-up Mica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mica#Built-up_mica)'.

Clearly this is not "cardboard" (as specified in the original question - now edited to say "material"!), since it is not paper-based, but, I hope it can be used for your application.